# process.stdout.pipe leads to "Error: This socket is closed"

Tags: node.js, stream, stdout

What am I doing wrong? Giving the following coffee-script:

```
logrotate = require 'logrotate-stream'
toLogFile = logrotate { file: 'wallboard.log', size: '20m', keep: 10}

console.log "Test before"
process.stdout.pipe toLogFile
console.log "Test after"
```

This puts out:

```
Test before
Error: This socket is closed.
  at WriteStream.Socket._writeGeneric (net.js:628:19)
  at WriteStream.Socket._write (net.js:679:8)
  at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:265:12)
  at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:252:5)
  at WriteStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:197:11)
  at WriteStream.Socket.write (net.js:606:40)
  at Console.log (console.js:53:16)
  at Object.<anonymous> (c:\vmcommon\dev\node\wallboard\_test_stdout.coffee:6:9)
  at Object.<anonymous> (c:\vmcommon\dev\node\wallboard\_test_stdout.coffee:1:1)
  at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
```

Why didn't work `process.stdout.pipe` as expected?

I'm trying to use [NPM: logrotate-stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/logrotate-stream) to redirect all console output to a file, which should be rotated by the library.

Comment: use forever module, it automatically generate log files and then you can use default system log-rotate.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I think this should work and I wouldn't like to use forever.

Comment: I think `process.stdout` and `process.stderr` are not supposed to be used as Readable streams. At least the [API docs](http://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_stdout) labels them as Writable streams.